# FeatureLayer Scale Settings in ArcGIS Silverlight API

Tags: arcgis-silverlight-api

Is there a way to translating between resolution and scale in the ArcGIS Silverlight API?

I am dynamically adding a Feature Layer to my map which should have a Min Scale value of 10,000.  The feature layer object has a setting for Minimum Resolution, but nothing for Scale values.

Does anyone know how I can set the Feature Layer to only show data below that scale?

Comment: Are you willing to assume a dpi for your display?  What if someone is using a projector?

Comment: Yes, I'd be willing to assume a DPI.

Answer (score 1):

In your code-behind, you can get your Map's scale and resolution, and divide them to get the constant between them. Then, just set the minimum resolution for the FeatureLayer, based on that.

vb.net:

```
'assuming variable MyMap as ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Map

Dim myFeatureLayer as New FeatureLayer() With { _
  ... 
  .MinimumResolution = 10000 * MyMap.Scale / MyMap.Resolution _
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
LayerInfo mfinfo = (map1.Layers["MFStock"] as ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer).Layers[1] as LayerInfo;
        mfinfo.MaxScale = 100000;
```